# Preview Outlook messages in .NET application

Tags: .net, outlook, ms-office, preview

Is there a component to allow us previewing Outlook email messages in a custom .NET application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/outlook_drag_drop_in_cs.aspx) would be a helpfull. also u can show the MailItem.